# Installing Android 4.1 or higher on Sony Tipo with permanently locked bootloader

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, bootloader-lock, sony-xperia-tipo

My operator (Telecom HU) has disabled unlocking the bootloader of my Sony Tipo. I would like to get Android 4.1 or higher on my device, but so far this seems impossible. I successfully installed ParadoxRom, but I found out that it is just a re-skin of the same android version I had before. My choice would be installing Cyanogenmod 10, but every tutorial I've seen so far relies on unlocking the bootloader, and as I found out from the service menu, this is impossible in my case.

[image]

If this doesn't prevent me from upgrading to 4.1 or higher, I would like to know what rom(s) can I use that are *actually* a newer operating system rather than a heavily edited ICS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [FlashTool](http://www.flashtool.net/)?

This is a particular software suite for flashing ROMs on Sony handsets, however, I am not 100% confident if it supports the Tipo.

The full forum thread that discusses about this tool can be found at [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2292598) so it might be worth a try to **read** the thread from beginning to end, to see if others have used it successfully on the Tipo.

If no luck, try posting a question there on that XDA thread, identical to the above question that is asked and wait for a while for someone to answer - *you do need to be patient, as people are answering in their own personal free time*.

**Be warned though**, using this tool, you could lose data, as a result of unlocking the boot-loader, there is a FTF (Flash Tool Firmware) file available for listed and detected devices, which can circumvent this and also can re-instate the boot-loader lock mechanism.

Comment: I've not used FlashTool before, and I don't quite understand how it's supposed to unlock the bootloader.

Comment: As I have stated in the answer, Flashtool is specifically to Sony handsets, those FTF files were floating around and put together as a compilation to aid in unlocking device by clicking on a blue icon representing a thunder or a spark to unlock. That is to the best of my knowledge, I have used it on Xperia Mini, unlocked bootloader, discovered upgrade to ICS was impossible because of bootloader state, had to lock it, then ICS upgrade happened, after that, I had to unlock it again to put LegacyXperia ROM on it and have not looked back since.

Comment: They key problem here is that I cannot unlock my bootloader and thus I'm unable to flash any sort of advanced firmware. You keep telling me I need some "FTF" files, but you never pointed me towards any directly, and I still have no idea if I will be able to unlock the bootloader or not.

Comment: All the FTF are contained in the FlashTool distribution which weighs in over 100Mb in size.